# In a GROUP BY, Is there a way to refer to a column in the SELECT clause whose name clashes with a column in the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given a the following query like:

```
with t1 as (
    select column1 as type, column2 as val1 from values
        (1,2)
        ,(3,4)
        ,(5,6)
)
select 
      case 
        when val1 > 2 then 'a'
        else 'b'
      end as type, 
       count(*)
from t1
group by type
;
```

I get the error `SQL compilation error: error line 9 at position 13 'T1.VAL1' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.` (using Snowflake).

It thinks that the `type` in `group by type` refers to `t1.type` instead of the `case...end as type` column in the SELECT clause (which is the one I meant to GROUP BY).

My question is there is any concise way to refer to the `case ... end as type` in the GROUP BY without copy and paste the whole `case ... end`  into the GROUP BY?

I know that I can explicitly refer to the `type` in `t1` using `GROUP BY t1.type`. Is there something like `GROUP BY this.type` (where `this` would refer to this query SELECT clause)?

Comment: Cant you simply change the name of the alias e.g. `type_2`?

Comment: @SalmanA Actually, I'm surprised this version of SQL is even throwing this error.  In SQL Server, I believe, the alias would mask the column name from the CTE and there would be no error.

Comment: @tim actually in SQL server it would throw the same error since GROUP BY is done before SELECT so a "column" in select is not visible in GROUP BY. MySQL allows that however (it is a "feature"), not sure about snowflake.

Comment: @SalmanA I can change the alias but I don't want to, I understand it's a valid workaround but let's say that the final result set must contain a column called TYPE so I would have to rename that TYPE_2 to TYPE somehow (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58373011/90580) . Snowflake also allows to use columns in the select in the group by (as long as it name it does not clash...)

Comment: @ecerulm there is a deleted answer that asks you to copy-paste the case expr to the group by clause. That should work but requires repeated code.

Comment: I know about that possibility (i mentioned in the question) maybe I should incorporate that and the renaming in my answer as workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join to move the definition to the `from` clause:

```
with t1 as (
      select column1 as type, column2 as val1
      from values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
     )
select v.type, count(*)
from t1 cross join lateral
     (values (case when t1.val1 > 2 then 'a' else 'b' end)
     ) v(type)
group by v.type;
```

I strongly recommend that you qualify *all* column references.  Do not rely on scoping rules to figure out what your references mean.  Lateral joins are one convenient mechanism for defining column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround for such situations is to add another step into the CTE:

```
with t1 as (
  select column1 as type, column2 as val1 from values
      (1,2)
      ,(3,4)
      ,(5,6)
)
, t2 as (
  select 
        case 
          when val1 > 2 then 'a'
          else 'b'
        end as type
  from t1
)
select type,
  count(*)
from t2
group by type
;
```

The intermediate `t2` will remove the `t1.type` from the scope so when you do the `GROUP BY type` it's `t2.type` which is the  `case...end` column.

I'm not sure this qualifies as a concise solution, but it's the closest I was able to get so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose "the other type" in double quotes, like

```
with t1 as (
    select column1 as type, column2 as val1 from values
        (1,2)
        ,(3,4)
        ,(5,6)
)
select 
      case 
        when val1 > 2 then 'a'
        else 'b'
      end as "type", 
       count(*)
from t1
group by "type"
;
```

Comment: well, that creates another column called *type* (lowercase) instead of *TYPE* (uppercase). You still have the same clash if the t1 had a column called *type*. This is just like renaming the column to avoid the clash.